# Vscode Intelephense doesn't recongnise any module in my codebase

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, intelephense

I've opened vscode today and intelephense didn't recongnise any of my imports/modules. Laravel pint which I also have installed is erroring out `exectuable not readable or lacks permissions pint`.

I am not sure what I changed.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons this could happen the one I encountered was because I had added my vendor directory to the vscode's excluded files and directories.

This theoretically shouldn't stop intelephense from indexing the project but due to the way vscode works it does.

simply removing the vendor directory from this array should fix the issue

[image]